# How to invite new members to an existing XMPP MultiUserChat aSmack

Tags: xmpp, asmack, multiuserchat

I want to make a group chat where every user can invite new users. To achieve this I have granted owner privileges to each user. The below method executes successfully without errors but the new users doesn't get an invitation.

```
muc.invite(friendsJID,"Group 1");
```

If the group creator invites the invitation becomes successful, other user cannot even though they are given the privileges.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Okay. I assume you are using Ejabberd as the XMPP server right. Therefore all you have to do is open up the GUI interface of ejabbberd
1. Click on vitual hosts 
2. Select the active domain from the Host column 
3. Click nodes and select the first running node
4. Click modules
5. There you have a module named "mod_muc"
6. Inside that change  {access_admin, muc_admin} to {access_admin, muc_member} and press restart.

Now it should work. Happy coding :)